# Conditionally display a title as link in MVC razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Since I am new to MVC Razor, I failed to find an efficient way to achieve what I want to do:
My purpose is to display in a chtml view two columns, one for Title and the other for its link, the title must be shown as link only if it has a link.

I tried this:

```
@model PaginatedList<MyProject.Models.Todo>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                  @{
                      int? length = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Link).ToString()?.Length;
                  }

                  @if (length is null)
                  {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Link)" target=_blank>
                      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                    </a>
                  }
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a href=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Link) target="_blank">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Link)</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

With the above code I get the Title displayed as a link despite its corresponding link field is empty. How to correct that ?

Comment: @length gets always the same value, and it is not null.

Comment: What **exactly** happens if you replace `int? length = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Link).ToString()?.Length;` with`int? length = item?.Link?.Length;`?

Comment: Now it works, the @length value changes, and the required titles don't get link format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making it complicated.

You can just simply check if it is `null` or just an empty string then use just title, other wise create hyper link with the text.

And you don't need to use the helper method to generate html inside another html like you are doing for anchor link, just use the `Model` property to render the values for `href` and inner text of the anchor element.

```
@if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Link))
{
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
}
else
{ 
    <a href ="@item.Link" target=_blank>@item.Title</a>
}
```

Hope it help!

Comment: PaginatedList<Todo>' does not contain a definition for 'Link' and no extension method 'Link' accepting a first argument of type 'PaginatedList<Todo>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: you need to use `@item` instead of `@Model`, i misunderstood that actually, see the updated post

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
int? length = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Link).ToString()?.Length;
```

to:

```
int? length = item?.Link?.Length;
```

This will get you the length of the `Link` - not the generated HTML.